# Gallery with image and text

Tags: android, image, text, gallery

I'm trying to build a gallery with text below the image but although I've followed every response founded in here I've yet to accomplish my objective.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext); 
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));

        TextView tv = new TextView(ll.getContext());

        tv.setTag(mText[position]);
        tv.setText(mText[position]);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(48, 48));
        ll.addView(tv); 

        // The preferred Gallery item background
        //i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return ll;
        //return i;
    }
```

I don't know why (and maybe it's the dumbest thing) but my images don't appear:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot to add the image view to the linear layout, simply add:

```
    ll.addView(i);
```

Also you are **not recycling** the convertView which could cause problems unless you have very few images and little to no scrolling of the grid.

You should check if convertView is null and if it is not simply change the text and image of the existing convertView.

Here is a good example for a custom grid view:
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/